# How to mock Window resize for my React Hook Component with Jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am using jest to test a component I made in react hooks. The component I made listens for window resize events from within useEffect(). From my test I can't find a way to trigger a window resize event. Here is my current attempt:

```
 describe ('window resize', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        global.innerWidth = 1500;
        global.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    })

    it('should do something to check window size', () => {
        // Do something
    });
});
```

Comment: Show the code under test